# Get rows in a range of time

Tags: mysql-5.5, datetime

I have a table with two columns that stores `TIME` type values. This is the `CREATE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `sdriving_turno` (
    `idturno` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idempresa` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `tipo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `hora_inicio` time DEFAULT NULL,
    `hora_fin` time DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idturno` , `idempresa`),
    KEY `fk_sdriving_turno_sdriving_empresa1_idx` (`idempresa`),
    CONSTRAINT `sdriving_turno_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idempresa`)
        REFERENCES `sdriving_empresa` (`idempresa`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need to get the records in a range of TIME, lets say I need to get all the records BETWEEN 14:00 and 17:00 and for that I made this query (it has some JOINS but it's not relevant on this topic):

```
SELECT 
    s.idregistros AS s__idregistros,
    s.maquinaemisorid AS s__maquinaemisorid,
    s.idoperador AS s__idoperador,
    s.idturno AS s__idturno,
    s.created_at AS s__created_at,
    s.updated_at AS s__updated_at,
    s2.idturno AS s2__idturno,
    s2.idempresa AS s2__idempresa,
    s2.tipo AS s2__tipo,
    s2.hora_inicio AS s2__hora_inicio,
    s2.hora_fin AS s2__hora_fin,
    s2.created_at AS s2__created_at,
    s2.updated_at AS s2__updated_at,
    s3.idmaquinaemisor AS s3__idmaquinaemisor,
    s3.idmaquina AS s3__idmaquina,
    s3.idemisor AS s3__idemisor,
    s3.created_at AS s3__created_at,
    s3.updated_at AS s3__updated_at,
    s4.idmaquina AS s4__idmaquina,
    s4.idempresa AS s4__idempresa,
    s4.patente AS s4__patente,
    s4.created_at AS s4__created_at,
    s4.updated_at AS s4__updated_at,
    s5.idoperador AS s5__idoperador,
    s5.idempresa AS s5__idempresa,
    s5.nombre AS s5__nombre,
    s5.rut AS s5__rut,
    s5.created_at AS s5__created_at,
    s5.updated_at AS s5__updated_at,
    s6.iddetalle_emisores AS s6__iddetalle_emisores,
    s6.idregistros AS s6__idregistros,
    s6.fecha_registro AS s6__fecha_registro,
    s6.dertalle_mensaje AS s6__dertalle_mensaje,
    s6.estado AS s6__estado,
    s6.revisado AS s6__revisado,
    s6.modo AS s6__modo,
    s6.remitente AS s6__remitente,
    s6.created_at AS s6__created_at,
    s6.updated_at AS s6__updated_at
FROM
    sdriving_registros_emisores s
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_turno s2 ON s.idturno = s2.idturno
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_maquina_emisor s3 ON s.maquinaemisorid = s3.idmaquinaemisor
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_maquina s4 ON s3.idmaquina = s4.idmaquina
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_operador s5 ON s.idoperador = s5.idoperador
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_detalle_emisores s6 ON s.idregistros = s6.idregistros
WHERE
    (s5.idempresa = '12'
        AND (s2.hora_inicio < '14:47'
        AND '14:47' > s2.hora_fin))
```

But when record has `hora_inicio` = 00:00:00 and `hora_fin` = 17:00:00 I get no results, why? What's wrong in my query?

**Note** 14:47 is the server data build through PHP if there is any way to get the records according to the current time in server just using SQL way let me know.

Comment: I guess you wanted `AND '14:47' < s2.hora_fin`

Comment: @ypercube aparently this fix the error, I'm doing some tests yet, will you answer a question in order to give your the points?

Comment: @ypercube I changed the values from `hora_inicio = 00:00:00` and `hora_fin = 17:00:00` to `hora_inicio = 17:00:00` and hora_fin = 00:00:00` and query stop working, how I can fix that?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `sdriving_turno` 
WHERE hora_inicio < NOW() AND hora_fin < '17:00:00'
```

you could also do something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM `sdriving_turno` 
WHERE hora_fin BETWEEN NOW() AND '18:00:00'
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is a way.
You can use now() function in sql to get the current time of the server while fetching records like the folowing query example..

select emp_id,now() from employee_tbl ;

it will return all the records of emp_id column along with the current server time.

Comment: have you even tried to read the question .. i think answer has been given on title only